# Ionic 2 - Service and modalCtrl

Tags: angular, ionic2

i´m quite new using ionic 2. I created a service to have all my filters (ModalCtrl) with a custom search input and checkbox (each one). Between those i send/get parameters but don´t know well how to keep the service active for keep waiting until the dismiss (get data from ModalCtrl) is trigger.

Basically all start by calling filterPost function from the html, it call the filterService (to start the ModalCtrl), after the user select the filter choices it send back the selected option but i cant get it from filterPost.

Im trying to do this because i need the filters in different areas, so i want to reuse it.

Thanks for the help

filterPost.ts

```
filterPost(){
    let data = this.filtros.filterThePost();
    console.log(data); //Here i get immediately undefined, dont wait dismiss
    this.titlepost = data;
}
```

filterService.ts

```
public filterThePost(){
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(MyFilterPost, {
      id_title: this.id_title //send active id
    });
    profileModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      //get data from modalCtrl, works nicely
      console.log("Got service: "+data, data.id, data.nombre);
      let info = {
        nombre: data.title,
        id: data.id
      }
      return info;
    });
    profileModal.present();                
}
```

myfilterpost.ts

```
saveFilter(id, name){       
    console.log("Selected: "+id, name);
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss({
        id: id,
        title: name
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning `info` from the modal to the service. However the service function itself returns nothing.
What you can do instead is send a callback function to the service that will set the **filterPost.ts** class variable `this.titlepost` in `onDidDismiss` callback.

Try:
In filterPost.ts

```
setTitlePost(data:any){
  this.titlepost=data;
}

filterPost(){
    this.filtros.filterThePost(this.setTitlePost.bind(this));//send callback
    console.log(data); //Here i get immediately undefined, dont wait dismiss
    //this.titlepost = data;
}
```

In your filterService.ts

```
public filterThePost(callbackfun:any){
    let profileModal = this.modalCtrl.create(MyFilterPost, {
      id_title: this.id_title //send active id
    });
    profileModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      //get data from modalCtrl, works nicely
      console.log("Got service: "+data, data.id, data.nombre);
      let info = {
        nombre: data.title,
        id: data.id
      }
      //return info;
      callbackfun(info);
    });
    profileModal.present();                
}
```